# Reset TCP connection one side

Tags: java, networking, iptables

Is there a way or tool to reset connection to one side only?
For example `tcpkill` sends RST packets to both sides, but I need to simulate case when connection left half opened: client closed connection, but server doesn't know about it.

Iptables configuration could be also helpful, when by some short timeout it starts rejecting client packets: `--reject-with tcp-reset`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a Java program, calling `close()` on an input stream or output stream obtained from a `Socket` will close one side of the connection.

However, you seem to be asking if one application can "half close" a TCP/IP connection belonging to another proccess

As far as I am aware, an ordinary use-space application (Java or not) cannot close or half-close another application's sockets.  Certainly not on a UNIX / Linux system.  Ditto for a privileged user-space application.

So this leaves you with tools like `tcpkill` that work by injecting raw packets.  It is possible to do the same kind of thing in Java using a native library (e.g. jpcap) to do the "dirty work" .... provided that your Java application is privileged.  But it would be simpler to just use `Process.exec(....)` to run `tcpkill` or equivalent.

---

> Iptables configuration could be also helpful, when by some short timeout it starts rejecting client packets: `--reject-with tcp-reset`

I wouldn't do that.  You risk leaving your system or virtual machine with an iptables configuration that causes problems, or worse.

Comment: Thanks, probably jpcap is a way to go.